# SQL View- WMS Viewparams - parameter for table name

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, parameters

I've made a SQL view using parameteres.
So, I did something like this:
SELECT * FROM '%tablename_parameter%'
The view is requesting data from a table by a parameter inserted from web page.
The geometry layer in table is Polygon or MultiPolygon.
The view is working, it shows data but it shows points not polygon.
I've saved the sql view to show me Polygon or MultiPolygon but still shows me points.
I don't know why or how to resolve this. Can someone help me?

Comment: did you register the view in geometry_columns? did you use a polygon or point symbolizer in your SLD?

Comment: Hello. I am sorry, but what do you mean if I have registered the view in geometry_columns? If you say that when I clicked for Geoserver to identify (guess) the geometry type and SRID - I did, Geoserver saw it MultyPolygon and the Correct SRID. And I don't use a SLD. Simple. But I will check that too just in case.

Comment: Done ! Yes, it was a SLD (point). Thank you very much. Must set it up by mistake when I've added the view to Geoserver ! Thank again